# Parametric Curve Tangent Equations

Tags: parametric

Let a curve be given in the parametrized form by:

$r(t) = (2\cos t, 2\sin t), 0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$

Find the equations of the tangents to the curve at each of its points $(X_0, Y_0)$.

Having gone through some text, it never really directly approaches a problem such as this. I have read through some articles on this website, and it provides varying solutions to this type of question and as such I can't tell what method is correct.

From the methods I have used for tangent vectors at a certain point:

$x = X_0 - 2s\sin t$ is the tangent equation for $X_0$ where $X_0 = 2\cos t$ for some $t$

$y = Y_0 + 2s\cos t$, for $Y_0$ where $Y_0= 2\sin t$ for the same $t$

If anyone could clarify if I am approaching this the right way or provide the correct method but not the answer then that would be appreciated.

Comment: You appear to be using the letter $t$for two different purposes, i.e. For parametrizing the curve and parametrizing the line. You need two different letters, so that for example  $x=X_0-2\lambda\sin t$ etc...

Comment: Ah yes I notice that now, thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 0):

The vector that locates the loci of points to the circle is given parametrically by

$$\vec r(t)=\hat x 2\cos t+\hat y2\sin t$$

At point $t_0$, we denote the vector $\vec r_0=\vec r(t_0)$.  The unit tangent $\hat u(t_0)$ to the curve at $t_0$ is

$$\begin{align}
\hat u(t_0)&=\left.\frac{\frac{d\vec r(t)}{dt}}{\left|\frac{d\vec r(t)}{dt}\right|}\right|_{t=t_0}\\\\
&=-\hat x\sin t_0+\hat y\cos t_0
\end{align}$$

The parametric equation of a line tangent to the circle at $\vec r_0$ is

$$\begin{align}
\vec R(s)&=\vec r_0+s\vec u_0\\\\
&=\hat x (2\cos t_0-s\sin t_0)+\hat y(2\sin t_0+s\cos t_0)
\end{align}$$

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{X(s)=2\cos (t_0)-\sin (t_0)\,s}$$

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{Y(s)=2\sin (t_0)+\cos (t_0)\,s}$$

Eliminating $s$ gives the equation of the line as

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{y_0Y=4-x_0X}$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really just want to give you the best answer I can.